# Como puedo cambiar de color al hacer clic en el botón

Tags: javascript

Al presionar el botón cambiar fondo no me va cambiando los colores. Lo extraño es que con colores como green o red si me cambia, los código de colores los encontré en internet

'use strict'

window.addEventListener("load",function(){

```
var titulo = document.getElementById("divTitulo");
var contenido = document.getElementById("divContenido");
var btnContenido = document.getElementById("btnContenido");

btnContenido.style.padding="10px";
btnContenido.style.fontSize="15px";
contenido.style.background="#FFFFFF";

function fondoContenido(){
    if(contenido.style.background=="#0099FF"){
        contenido.style.background="#009966";
    }else if(contenido.style.background=="#009966"){
        contenido.style.background="#FFFFFF";
    }else{
        contenido.style.background="#0099FF";
    }
}

btnContenido.addEventListener("click",function(){
    fondoContenido();
});
```

});

---

codigo httml:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="practica.js"></script>
        <title>Mi practica</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="divContenido">
            <h2 id="miTitulo">Limbert_Art</h2>
            <p>Limbert_Art es un emprendimiento de retratos realistas, que inicialmente nace por el 
                deseo de aprender a dibujar personas, y con el pasar del tiempo la técnica se fue
                perfeccionando hacia el realismo.</p>
            <p>Los materiales que se usan para los retratos son:<br>
                Cartulina: marfil y escolar.<br>
                Lapices: grafito y colores profesionales.
            </p>
            <p>
                <button id="btnContenido">Cambiar Color</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body> 
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict'

window.addEventListener( "load", function() {
    var titulo = document.getElementById( "divTitulo" );
    var contenido = document.getElementById( "divContenido" );
    var btnContenido = document.getElementById( "btnContenido" );
    btnContenido.style.padding = "10px";
    btnContenido.style.fontSiz e= "15px";
    contenido.style.background = "FFFFFF";
    let color = "a";
    function fondoContenido() {
        if( color == "a" ) {
            contenido.style.background = "#009966";
            color = "b";
        }
        else if( color == "b" ) {
            contenido.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
            color = "c";
        }
        else{
            contenido.style.background = "#0099FF";
            color = "a";
        }
    }

    btnContenido.addEventListener( "click", function() {
        fondoContenido();
    });

});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="practica.js"></script>
        <title>Mi practica</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="divContenido">
            <h2 id="miTitulo">Limbert_Art</h2>
            <p>Limbert_Art es un emprendimiento de retratos realistas, que inicialmente nace por el 
                deseo de aprender a dibujar personas, y con el pasar del tiempo la técnica se fue
                perfeccionando hacia el realismo.</p>
            <p>Los materiales que se usan para los retratos son:<br>
                Cartulina: marfil y escolar.<br>
                Lapices: grafito y colores profesionales.
            </p>
            <p>
                <button id="btnContenido">Cambiar Color</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body> 
    
</html>
```

Dado que la comparación de colores es problemática, lo que hice fue crear una variable que "acompaña" a los cambios de color, y es con ella que hago las comparaciones para saber cual es el color a aplicar.
Espero que te sea de utilidad!!.

Comment: muchas gracias lo probaré